# Batch command to open in two different monitor

Tags: javascript, batch-file

Hi I need a  script where the script will open 2 web pages with a sepcfic url and if I have 2 monitors it should display page in 1 page in 1 monitor and 2 IE page in another monitor..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about redirecting the output to different monitor but you can use the below command to open a URL in your desired browser. Example, opening `google.com` in `firefox`

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox>firefox.exe www.google.com
```